# SQL query returning only values from first column in SELECT statement

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

If I run the query below in DBVisualizer it returns one long row of values (which is the expected and correct result), with the same columns repeated (from the same table in an Oracle 11 database). So, for instance, if 3 of the columns are **ID*, **FIRST_NAME** and **LAST NAME** it would look something like this (my apologies for the crude "diagram"):

```
+-----+------------+-----------+----+------------+-----------+
| ID  | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
| 2   | John       | Doe       | 3  | Jane       | Doe       |
```

However, if I run the same native query in a java web app (using Hibernate 3.0, JPA 2.1) with an Entity class mapped to the aforementioned Oracle 11 database, with the following code snippet:

```
List<ForeignParty> queryResult = null;
    String sqlQuery = "SELECT f.*, p.POLICY_1_NUM, p.TOTAL_PAYOUT_AMT, f1.*, f2.*, f3.*, f4.* " +
                      "FROM FOREIGN_PARTY f " +
                      "LEFT JOIN POLICY_PAYMENT p ON f.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID = p.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID " +
                      "LEFT JOIN FOREIGN_PARTY f1 ON f.RELATED_PARTY_ID1 = f1.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID " +
                      "LEFT JOIN FOREIGN_PARTY f2 ON f.RELATED_PARTY_ID2 = f2.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID " +
                      "LEFT JOIN FOREIGN_PARTY f3 ON f.RELATED_PARTY_ID3 = f3.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID " +
                      "LEFT JOIN FOREIGN_PARTY f4 ON f.RELATED_PARTY_ID4 = f4.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID " +
                      "WHERE " +
                      "f.PARTY_TYPE_ID = '2' " +
                      "AND f.SOURCE_SYSTEM = :sourceSystem " +
                      "AND f.SOURCE_CLIENT_ID = :sourceClientId";
    query = emFatca.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, ForeignParty.class);
    query.setParameter("sourceSystem", sourceSystem);
    query.setParameter("sourceClientId", sourceClientId);
    try {
        queryResult = query.getResultList();
        //This statement ensures that the PolicyPayment object does not go out of session scope
        for (ForeignParty fp : queryResult) {
            fp.getPolicyPaymentCollection().size();
        } 
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        nre.getMessage();
    }
    return queryResult;
```

...it only returns the values for all columns as specified by **f.**, the first item in the **SELECT** statement above. I verified that by temporarily moving the **f4.** item in the **SELECT** statement to be the first item in that statement, and then saw that the values in the output matched those for that particular alias. I am wondering if this has to do with the fact that this is returning multiple columns of the same name and same  Entity in one record or row, rather than separate records?? Would I need to use something like **SqlResultSetMapping** to individually set aliases for each iteration of the results? I am thinking that would be a lot of work, since there would be many columns/aliases to define. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I might be premature with this (as I am still adding the code), but thought I would share it. I _think_ the cause is the fact that Hibernate does not raise an exception about the resultset being ambiguous, and just adds the values from the first SELECT column(s). So, I am manually setting individual column names for each alias from the JOIN statements with their own aliases. So, for instance, instead of using _f1.*_ I am manually adding **f1.FOREIGN_PARTY_ID AS F1_FOREIGN_PARTY_ID**, and so on. A lot of manual coding, yes, but  if this solves my problem I am ok with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`createNativeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createNativeQuery-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) takes an Entity class and not a DTO class. If you want to map a native query to a non-Entity result you need to use [`@SqlResultSetMapping`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-sqlresultsetmapping/) with a [`@ConstructorResult`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/ConstructorResult.html).

Comment: Hi Vlad, thank you for your reply! The class **ForeignParty.class** referenced in the parameter of my createNativeQuery call above is an Entity class. I guess the unique thing about this app is I have one or more of auto-generated IDs of records inserted into specific columns of a "master" record in the database. Because of that, the resultset could have repeated instances of the same columns that are mapped in an  Entity class (ForeignParty.class). This is unlike a "typical" resultset that contains one or more records, but with only one set of columns from an Entity class, in each record.

Comment: I am going to investigate your link further in your reply. Thank you once again for helping me.

Comment: My apologies, I meant to do that sooner. Thank you for your help Vlad!   :-)